# SQL Group by Transpose

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, pivot

I have the following Table charges

```
charges:
|Quantity|Timestamp| Charge|
|--------+---------+-------|
|       1|8/01/2020| Yearly|
|       2|8/01/2020|Monthly|
|       1|8/01/2020|Monthly|
|       2|8/02/2020| Yearly|
|       1|8/02/2020|Monthly|
|       1|8/02/2020|Monthly|
```

Using the following query gets my the counts by Charge and Date

```
Query:
select SUM(Quantity), Timestamp, Charge 
from charges 
group by Timestamp, Charge 

Result:
|Sum|Timestamp| Charge|
|---+---------+-------|
|  1|8/01/2020| Yearly|
|  3|8/01/2020|Monthly|
|  2|8/02/2020| Yearly|
|  2|8/02/2020|Monthly|
```

Is there a way to transpose this to get the following?

```
Expected:
|Timestamp|Yearly|Monthly|
|---------+------+-------|
|8/01/2020|     1|      3|
|8/02/2020|     2|      2|
```

Thank you.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    timestamp,
    sum(case when charge = 'Yearly'  then charge else 0 end) yearly,
    sum(case when charge = 'Monthly' then charge else 0 end) monthly
from charges
group by timestamp
```

Comment: Thank you GMB. You are a hero!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your RDBMS you can use `PIVOT` function.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT QUANTITY, TIMESTAMP, CHARGE
          FROM CHARGES C) C PIVOT (SUM (QUANTITY)
                            FOR CHARGE
                            IN ('Yearly', 'Monthly'))
```